# Jquery wrapp element in label?

Tags: jquery, append, wrapper

I am making some checkbox styling, but iCheck hae some issues with my control, thta way i decided to make my own iCheck. What i need i have this element

```
<input type="checkbox" class="vvCheck">
<input type="radio" class="vvCheck">
```

With jquery i want ot make someting like this

For checkbox

```
<label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="vvCheck">
  <i></i>
</label>
```

And for radio

```
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" class="vvCheck">
  <i></i>
</label>
```

Can i make in one function, just call like this

```
vvCheck();
```

Txanks

Here is working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/yxwvn9at/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .wrap() like

```js
function vvCheck() {
  $('.vvCheck[type="checkbox"]').wrap('<label class="checkbox" />').after('<i />')
  $('.vvCheck[type="radio"]').wrap('<label class="radio" />').after('<i />')
}
vvCheck();
```

```css
label.checkbox {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
label.checkbox i {
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  background: red;
}
label.radio {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
label.radio i {
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="vvCheck">
<input type="radio" class="vvCheck">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function vvCheck() {
    var liInsideLabel = '<li></li>';
    var radioLabel = '<label class="radio"></label>';   
    var checkboxLabel = '<label class="radio"></label>';

    $('input[type=radio].vvCheck').each(function(){
      $(this).wrap(radioLabel).after(liInsideLabel);      
     });

    $('input[type=checkbox].vvCheck').each(function(){
      $(this).wrap(checkboxLabel).after(liInsideLabel);       
    });
}
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yxwvn9at/3/)**